rodio panic when trying to play Sink with reverb effect
UPDATED: This issue is officially a bug.
I'm adding a reverb effect following this example, but panic when trying to play the sink.
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at /feelslikehome/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rodio-0.19.0/src/conversions/channels.rs:100:13:
attempt to subtract with overflow
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
fatal runtime error: Rust panics must be rethrown

This is what I did:
        
    fn main() {
        
        // This snippet is from the example
        let (_stream, handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
        let sink = rodio::Sink::try_new(&handle).unwrap();
        let file = std::fs::File::open("assets/music.ogg").unwrap();

        // This is originally a function that returns (Mode, Sink, Stream) tuple
        match Decoder::new(BufReader::new(file)) {
            Ok(decoder) => {
                let mode = get_mode();
                if mode == Mode::Bass {
                    // Duration is just an arbitrary number, I tried 0, milliseconds, etc.
                    let reverb = decoder.buffered().reverb(Duration::from_secs(30), 1.0);
                    sink.append(reverb);
                } else {
                    sink.append(decoder);
                }
                // Try playing it right away, it panicked!
                sink.play();
                Some((mode, sink, stream))
            }
            Err(e) => {
                info!("Failed to create decoder: {:?}", e);
                None
            }
        }
     }

     fn get_mode() -> Mode {
         Mode::Bass
     }

     enum Mode {
        case Bass
     }
     

I suspect calling the buffered() is the problem, but it is needed because the reverb requires a clone-able source. There's no API to unbuffered the decoder. When I tried to play the sink right away, it was also panic.
Any pointers?

Is that with a mono or stereo input?

Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example, i.e. that smallest runnable snippet of code and audio file we can run for ourselves and observe the problem.

@jmb mono. I don't configure it, so it should be the default.

@ChayimFriedman i updated the description

This is officially a bug. I posted the solution here to solve the panic. The bug is in the size_hint function of the channels.rs rodio. This line:
(size + consumed) / self.from as usize * self.to as usize
    - self.next_output_sample_pos as usize

Becomes:
((size + consumed) / self.from as usize * self.to as usize).saturating_sub(self.next_output_sample_pos as usize)


Using the linked example and the code you provided, I tried to put together a minimal reproducible example, but it's working with a sample song.  I suspect there is some arithmetic overflow when applying reverb to the specific song you're playing.  Could you check if it happens with the linked audio file too?
use rodio::{Decoder, Source};
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let (_stream, handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
    let sink = rodio::Sink::try_new(&handle).unwrap();

    let file = std::fs::File::open("assets/music.ogg").unwrap();

    match Decoder::new(BufReader::new(file)) {
        Ok(decoder) => {
            let reverb = decoder.buffered().reverb(Duration::from_millis(70), 1.0);
            sink.append(reverb);
        }
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to create decoder: {:?}", e);
        }
    }
    
    sink.sleep_until_end();
}

